# Spring Jersey and Spring boot together

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jersey

I recently got to know about JAX-RS and jersey to be its one of the implementation. I was using Spring boot until now to work with rest apis.

I was just experimenting by putting both the dependencies together. So my pom looks like :

```
   <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jersey</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

now I added a controller which is having endpoints like :

```
@Service
@Path("/")
@RestController
public class TestController {

    @GET
    @Path("/test")
    public String test() {
        return "Hello World";
    }

    @GetMapping("/test2")
    public String test2() {
        return "Hello World - spring";
    }
}
```

Now if I try to hot these endpoints like :

```
http://localhost:8080/test
```

and

```
http://localhost:8080/test2
```

I only get a response for jersey ("Hello World").

Can anyone help me on how does it registers these endpoints and why @GetMapping endpoint is not being recognised.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You should not mix JAX-RS (`@PATH`. `@GET`, etc) and Spring MVC (`@RestController`, `@GetMapping`, etc) in the same class, or even, ideally, in the same application. From a Spring-only perspective, `@Service` and `@RestController` should not be used together either.

If you really want to mix Jersey and Spring MVC, you should do so in separate classes. You’ll also need to [configure Jersey to run as a filter and to forward requests that it cannot handle](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68298555/1384297) so that Spring MVC gets a chance to do so.